# android "MediaProjection" api in not working in chrome os

Tags: android, chromebook

I am using android "android.media.projection.MediaProjection"  to capture screenshot . Application works perfectly in android device but if same app installed in Chromebook ,application will only capture screenshot of android apps  discard chrome web app screenshot even desktop screen also not captured.

Comment: hey, did you found any solution?

Comment: No not yet found any solution.

Comment: Hi @RakshithRaj : did you find any solution?